# How to resize button containing svg image

Tags: java, svg, javafx, resize

I want to place a svg image inside a button, and then I want to be able to resize the button to any size.

First, this is how I've done the loading and placing of the svg image inside the button:

```
SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
        svg.setContent("M87.5,50.002C87.5,29.293,70.712,12.5,50,12.5c-20.712,0-37.5,16.793-37.5,37.502C12.5,70.712,29.288,87.5,50,87.5
        c6.668,0,12.918-1.756,18.342-4.809c0.61-0.22,1.049-0.799,1.049-1.486c0-0.622-0.361-1.153-0.882-1.413l0.003-0.004l-6.529-4.002
        L61.98,75.79c-0.274-0.227-0.621-0.369-1.005-0.369c-0.238,0-0.461,0.056-0.663,0.149l-0.014-0.012
        C57.115,76.847,53.64,77.561,50,77.561c-15.199,0-27.56-12.362-27.56-27.559c0-15.195,12.362-27.562,27.56-27.562
        c14.322,0,26.121,10.984,27.434,24.967C77.428,57.419,73.059,63,69.631,63c-1.847,0-3.254-1.23-3.254-3.957
        c0-0.527,0.176-1.672,0.264-2.111l4.163-19.918l-0.018,0c0.012-0.071,0.042-0.136,0.042-0.21c0-0.734-0.596-1.33-1.33-1.33h-7.23
        c-0.657,0-1.178,0.485-1.286,1.112l-0.025-0.001l-0.737,3.549c-1.847-3.342-5.629-5.893-10.994-5.893
        c-10.202,0-19.877,9.764-19.877,21.549c0,8.531,5.101,14.775,13.632,14.775c4.75,0,9.587-2.727,12.665-7.035l0.088,0.527
        c0.615,3.342,9.843,7.576,15.121,7.576c7.651,0,16.617-5.156,16.617-19.932l-0.022-0.009C87.477,51.13,87.5,50.569,87.5,50.002z
         M56.615,56.844c-1.935,2.727-5.101,5.805-9.763,5.805c-4.486,0-7.212-3.166-7.212-7.738c0-6.422,5.013-12.754,12.049-12.754
        c3.958,0,6.245,2.551,7.124,4.486L56.615,56.844z");

Button button = new Button();
        button.setGraphic(svg);
```

I've tried putting the SVGPath inside a Group object, and then I've scaled that Group, like this:

```
Group graphics = new Group();
graphics.getChildren().add(svg);
graphics.getTransforms().add(new Scale(0.2, 0.2, 0 , 10));

Button button = new Button();
button.setGraphic(graphics);
```

And that does change the size of the svg image. The problem is that the size of the button doesn't change accordingly. It has the same size as if the image was never rescaled. It doesn't matter if I set the max size of the button. I can only make the button bigger, but not smaller.

There seems to be very limited documentation on using SVG images in JavaFx, so if anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** @ItachiUchiha pointed out that I can just rescale the button using `setScaleX(..) and`setScaleY(..), and the svg image inside will get rescaled with it. However, doing this doesn't seem to change the size property of the button. This means that the pane containing the button will still occupy the same space as if the button wasn't rescaled. And setting a max size on the pane doesn't help. In addition, the setScaleY and X methods rescales all of the button, including the borders of the button. This gives the button another appearance than buttons containing plain text. My pane will contain both buttons with svg content and buttons with plain text content, and they should all look the same apart from their content.

**Update 2:** @ItachiUchiha's edited response made everything clear. Marked as the answer.

Comment: Any reasons for re-sizing the svg instead of the button itself?

Comment: I am asking how to resize the button itself. Although I need to resize the svg image as well since my original picture is too big. I can't have just half of the picture getting shown in the button. But if there's a way to resize the button so that the svg gets resized as well, that will work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVG images can be re-size themselves and fit its container. You can re-size the button and the SVG image will fit its boundary.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setGraphic(svg);
// Re-size the button
button.setScaleX(0.5);
button.setScaleY(0.5);
```

---

**EDIT** - To resize buttons according to the parent.

If you want to re-size button according to the Parent and also scale the image according to it. You can bind the scale Property of the image to the height and width of the Button. Whenever the size of the Parent changes, change the button's prefSize as well.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    private final int MIN_BUTTON_SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
        svg.setContent("M87.5,50.002C87.5,29.293,70.712,12.5,50,12.5c-20.712,0-37.5,16.793-37.5,37.502C12.5,70.712,29.288,87.5,50,87.5" +
                "c6.668,0,12.918-1.756,18.342-4.809c0.61-0.22,1.049-0.799,1.049-1.486c0-0.622-0.361-1.153-0.882-1.413l0.003-0.004l-6.529-4.002" +
        "L61.98,75.79c-0.274-0.227-0.621-0.369-1.005-0.369c-0.238,0-0.461,0.056-0.663,0.149l-0.014-0.012" +
        "C57.115,76.847,53.64,77.561,50,77.561c-15.199,0-27.56-12.362-27.56-27.559c0-15.195,12.362-27.562,27.56-27.562" +
        "c14.322,0,26.121,10.984,27.434,24.967C77.428,57.419,73.059,63,69.631,63c-1.847,0-3.254-1.23-3.254-3.957" +
        "c0-0.527,0.176-1.672,0.264-2.111l4.163-19.918l-0.018,0c0.012-0.071,0.042-0.136,0.042-0.21c0-0.734-0.596-1.33-1.33-1.33h-7.23" +
        "c-0.657,0-1.178,0.485-1.286,1.112l-0.025-0.001l-0.737,3.549c-1.847-3.342-5.629-5.893-10.994-5.893" +
        "c-10.202,0-19.877,9.764-19.877,21.549c0,8.531,5.101,14.775,13.632,14.775c4.75,0,9.587-2.727,12.665-7.035l0.088,0.527" +
        "c0.615,3.342,9.843,7.576,15.121,7.576c7.651,0,16.617-5.156,16.617-19.932l-0.022-0.009C87.477,51.13,87.5,50.569,87.5,50.002z" +
        "M56.615,56.844c-1.935,2.727-5.101,5.805-9.763,5.805c-4.486,0-7.212-3.166-7.212-7.738c0-6.422,5.013-12.754,12.049-12.754" +
        "c3.958,0,6.245,2.551,7.124,4.486L56.615,56.844z");

        Button buttonWithGraphics = new Button();
        buttonWithGraphics.setGraphic(svg);

        // Bind the Image scale property to the buttons size
        svg.scaleXProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.widthProperty().divide(100));
        svg.scaleYProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.heightProperty().divide(100));

        // Declare a minimum size for the button
        buttonWithGraphics.setMinSize(MIN_BUTTON_SIZE, MIN_BUTTON_SIZE);

        root.getChildren().addAll(buttonWithGraphics);
        root.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldBounds, newBounds) -> {
                double size = Math.max(MIN_BUTTON_SIZE, Math.min(newBounds.getWidth(), newBounds.getHeight()));
                buttonWithGraphics.setPrefSize(size, size);
            }
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The **central** image is the *default size*, so this works on decreasing as well as increasing the Button size.

[image]

**N.B.** - *You can calculate and use different values for height and width of the button.*

Comment: Thanks! I just have two questions: 1: Why doesn't `button.setPrefSize(..)` work if I remove `button.setMinSize(..)`? I mean, the `button.setMinSize(..) doesn't do anything when `button.setPrefSize(..) is set and the button can take as much space as it likes, so why does it matter? 2: Is there anyway that I can get this to work if I want to display a square svg image inside a rectangular button while keeping the proportions of the image? Because with this implementation, the image gets stretched.

Comment: 1. Unless specified externally, for a button, its minimum size is its preferred size. So, we need to define `button.setMinSize(..)` to make the button grow smaller than its normal size. 2. Yes you can, just keep the scaling for image proportional to the size of the button.

Comment: See my last update: Why doesn't this work if I use this new image instead? The picture doesn't get resized according to its `Button`.

Comment: Ideally, you should start a new question and not stack up old question. Nevertheless, I checked the SVGPath and I think you need to fix it first. Can you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qruudrs2/) with your path?

Comment: Okay. I just figured it would be considered a duplicate.You want me to start a  new question? Anyhow, what do you want me to do with jsfiddle? It seems to contain a compiler for JavaScript, not regular Java.

Comment: You can easily check whether the SVGPath that you are using is correct or not on the JSFiddle.

Comment: Well I don't get any output, i.e. no image, when I test the `SVGPath` in JSFiddle. But I can see the picture if I load it in the program in this answer. What does that mean?

Comment: I am not sure, but if I would have to take a wild guess, I would suggest you to double check your Path.

Comment: I started a new question about this instead.