# Svg on Button in JavaFX

Tags: java, button, svg, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am working with pure-java JavaFX(no FXML) to build layouts and I wanted to make a HBox with buttons that contain SVG images instead of text.

But instead of what I expected to see I ended up with this:
[image]

I have tried setting several combinations of parameters such as maxSize, minSize, prefSize but to no avail.

Current code: [gist](https://gist.github.com/thepieterdc/8a5eed00fca5074d3157)

Comment: This
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702977/javafx-how-to-resize-button-containing-svg-image
may be of further interest to you.

Comment: your link to the code is not working. Kindly edit the question to post the code so that other users might benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by resizing the svg images in InkScape. Apparently setMaxSize etc. only resize the button itself instead of the graphics on it.

Comment: Or you could resize the image on load using the Image constructor with scaling possiblilities.
Or you could use the setFitWidth and setFitHeight methods of ImageView that displays the image.