# How to dynamically resize an svg in javafx according to the size of the region

Tags: svg, javafx, resize

I'm keen on svg and would like to put many of them in my User Interface. But I have a problem with the size of svg. I would like to load any svg I retrieve as a parameter and resize it dynamically to the size of the control.
All the examples I found are resize thanks to the "rescale" method (as found in the following article [JavaFX: How to resize button containing svg image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702977/javafx-how-to-resize-button-containing-svg-image).

But since I have no idea of the size of the original svg I don't know what factor to apply in the rescale method.
So, my question is how do I generify the following code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
private final int MIN_BUTTON_SIZE = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    HBox root = new HBox();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
    svg.setContent("M87.5,50.002C87.5,29.293,70.712,12.5,50,12.5c-20.712,0-37.5,16.793-37.5,37.502C12.5,70.712,29.288,87.5,50,87.5" +
            "c6.668,0,12.918-1.756,18.342-4.809c0.61-0.22,1.049-0.799,1.049-1.486c0-0.622-0.361-1.153-0.882-1.413l0.003-0.004l-6.529-4.002" +
    "L61.98,75.79c-0.274-0.227-0.621-0.369-1.005-0.369c-0.238,0-0.461,0.056-0.663,0.149l-0.014-0.012" +
    "C57.115,76.847,53.64,77.561,50,77.561c-15.199,0-27.56-12.362-27.56-27.559c0-15.195,12.362-27.562,27.56-27.562" +
    "c14.322,0,26.121,10.984,27.434,24.967C77.428,57.419,73.059,63,69.631,63c-1.847,0-3.254-1.23-3.254-3.957" +
    "c0-0.527,0.176-1.672,0.264-2.111l4.163-19.918l-0.018,0c0.012-0.071,0.042-0.136,0.042-0.21c0-0.734-0.596-1.33-1.33-1.33h-7.23" +
    "c-0.657,0-1.178,0.485-1.286,1.112l-0.025-0.001l-0.737,3.549c-1.847-3.342-5.629-5.893-10.994-5.893" +
    "c-10.202,0-19.877,9.764-19.877,21.549c0,8.531,5.101,14.775,13.632,14.775c4.75,0,9.587-2.727,12.665-7.035l0.088,0.527" +
    "c0.615,3.342,9.843,7.576,15.121,7.576c7.651,0,16.617-5.156,16.617-19.932l-0.022-0.009C87.477,51.13,87.5,50.569,87.5,50.002z" +
    "M56.615,56.844c-1.935,2.727-5.101,5.805-9.763,5.805c-4.486,0-7.212-3.166-7.212-7.738c0-6.422,5.013-12.754,12.049-12.754" +
    "c3.958,0,6.245,2.551,7.124,4.486L56.615,56.844z");

    Button buttonWithGraphics = new Button();
    buttonWithGraphics.setGraphic(svg);

    // Bind the Image scale property to the buttons size
    svg.scaleXProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.widthProperty().divide(100));
    svg.scaleYProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.heightProperty().divide(100));

    // Declare a minimum size for the button
    buttonWithGraphics.setMinSize(MIN_BUTTON_SIZE, MIN_BUTTON_SIZE);

    root.getChildren().addAll(buttonWithGraphics);
    root.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldBounds, newBounds) -> {
            double size = Math.max(MIN_BUTTON_SIZE, Math.min(newBounds.getWidth(), newBounds.getHeight()));
            buttonWithGraphics.setPrefSize(size, size);
        }
    );

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I guess this is linked with the following lines:

```
 svg.scaleXProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.widthProperty().divide(100));
```

Comment: at least add the source to your code.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702977/how-to-resize-button-containing-svg-image

Answer (score 1):

1. create a resizable canvas, you can find details [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/javafx-tip-1-resizable-canvas.html)
2. canvas can be scaled, and also graphic context can also be scale

```
var gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.scale(0.1, 0.1);
```

3. use gc to draw the svg path, line, circle, etc.

sample code here:

```
    var canvas = new ResizableCanvas() {
      @Override
      public void draw() {
        var gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.save();//make sure you save the status here and restore after all operations are finished
        //System.out.print(getWidth()+" ");
        //System.out.println(getHeight());
        var width = getWidth();
        var height = getHeight();
        gc.clearRect(0,0,width, height);
        gc.scale(width/512.002, height/512.002);

        gc.beginPath();
        gc.setFill(Color.web("#2D4961"));
        gc.appendSVGPath("""
          M399.994,0H112.008C94.337,0,80.009,14.327,80.009,31.999v342.624
          c0.08,16.159,8.288,31.191,21.839,39.998l145.433,94.796c5.304,3.448,12.135,3.448,17.439,0l145.433-94.556
          c13.551-8.808,21.759-23.839,21.839-39.998V31.999C431.993,14.327,417.665,0,399.994,0z M399.994,68.477
          c-6.872-6.24-15.399-10.352-24.559-11.839c-1.496-9.2-5.64-17.759-11.919-24.639h36.478V68.477z M148.486,31.999
          c-6.264,6.864-10.408,15.391-11.919,24.559c-9.168,1.512-17.695,5.656-24.559,11.919V31.999H148.486z M256.001,476.858
          l-26.479-17.199c11.047-4.6,20.327-12.623,26.479-22.879c6.152,10.256,15.431,18.279,26.479,22.879L256.001,476.858z
           M399.994,374.622c0.008,5.424-2.728,10.48-7.28,13.439l-91.756,59.917c-20.895-1.592-37.022-19.039-36.958-39.998
          c0-4.416-3.584-8-8-8s-8,3.584-8,8c0.064,20.959-16.063,38.406-36.958,39.998l-91.756-59.917c-4.552-2.96-7.288-8.016-7.28-13.439
          V103.995c0-17.671,14.327-31.998,31.998-31.998c4.416,0,8-3.584,8-8c0-17.671,14.327-31.999,31.999-31.999h143.993
          c17.671,0,31.999,14.327,31.999,31.999c0,4.416,3.584,8,8,8c17.671,0,31.999,14.327,31.999,31.998L399.994,374.622L399.994,374.622z""");
        gc.fill();
        gc.setFill(Color.web("#44637F"));
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.appendSVGPath("""
          M80.009,31.999v271.987l0,0c8.84,0,15.999-7.16,15.999-15.999V31.999
          c0-8.84,7.16-15.999,15.999-15.999h271.987c8.84,0,15.999-7.16,15.999-15.999H112.008C94.329,0,80.009,14.327,80.009,31.999z""");
        gc.fill();
        gc.setFill(Color.web("#123247"));
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.appendSVGPath("""
          M410.154,414.861c13.551-8.808,21.759-23.839,21.839-39.998V55.997l0,0
          c-8.84,0-15.999,7.16-15.999,15.999v304.466c0,8.04-4.024,15.551-10.719,19.999L269.28,487.097
          c-8.304,5.56-13.287,14.887-13.279,24.879l0,0c3.096,0.008,6.12-0.88,8.72-2.56L410.154,414.861z""");
        gc.fill();
        gc.restore();
      }
    };

    canvas.widthProperty().bind(canvas.heightProperty());
    canvas.heightProperty().bind(stage.getScene().heightProperty().multiply(0.1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above tries to do it dynamically, although (as you said) fails to do it in respect to the original `SvgPath` size.

I would recommend doing it like that:

```
double size = 30;
svg.setScaleX(size / svg.boundsInLocalProperty().get().getWidth());
svg.setScaleY(size / svg.boundsInLocalProperty().get().getHeight());
```

This will scale your `SvgPath` to `size`.