# SVGPath does not get resized correctly in Button

Tags: java, html, svg, javafx

I'm trying to use an SVG image in a `Button` in a JavaFX program. I'm using a program from a [question I asked a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702977/how-to-resize-button-containing-svg-image?answertab=votes#tab-top) to load the SVG image using `SVGPath`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestSVGPath2 extends Application {

    private final static String OLD_SVG = "M87.5,50.002C87.5,29.293,70.712,12.5,50,12.5c-20.712,0-37.5,16.793-37.5,37.502C12.5,70.712,29.288,87.5,50,87.5"
            + "c6.668,0,12.918-1.756,18.342-4.809c0.61-0.22,1.049-0.799,1.049-1.486c0-0.622-0.361-1.153-0.882-1.413l0.003-0.004l-6.529-4.002"
            + "L61.98,75.79c-0.274-0.227-0.621-0.369-1.005-0.369c-0.238,0-0.461,0.056-0.663,0.149l-0.014-0.012"
            + "C57.115,76.847,53.64,77.561,50,77.561c-15.199,0-27.56-12.362-27.56-27.559c0-15.195,12.362-27.562,27.56-27.562"
            + "c14.322,0,26.121,10.984,27.434,24.967C77.428,57.419,73.059,63,69.631,63c-1.847,0-3.254-1.23-3.254-3.957"
            + "c0-0.527,0.176-1.672,0.264-2.111l4.163-19.918l-0.018,0c0.012-0.071,0.042-0.136,0.042-0.21c0-0.734-0.596-1.33-1.33-1.33h-7.23"
            + "c-0.657,0-1.178,0.485-1.286,1.112l-0.025-0.001l-0.737,3.549c-1.847-3.342-5.629-5.893-10.994-5.893"
            + "c-10.202,0-19.877,9.764-19.877,21.549c0,8.531,5.101,14.775,13.632,14.775c4.75,0,9.587-2.727,12.665-7.035l0.088,0.527"
            + "c0.615,3.342,9.843,7.576,15.121,7.576c7.651,0,16.617-5.156,16.617-19.932l-0.022-0.009C87.477,51.13,87.5,50.569,87.5,50.002z"
            + "M56.615,56.844c-1.935,2.727-5.101,5.805-9.763,5.805c-4.486,0-7.212-3.166-7.212-7.738c0-6.422,5.013-12.754,12.049-12.754"
            + "c3.958,0,6.245,2.551,7.124,4.486L56.615,56.844z";
    private final static String NEW_SVG = "M10,304v26.8h190.8V304H10z M227.8,304v26.8h271.8c0,0-27.8-26.8-64.5-26.8H227.8z M552.9,304v26.8h164.5l-9.8-26.8H552.9z M835.3,304l-9.8,26.8h163V304H835.3z M10,356.2V383h190.8v-26.8H10z M227.8,356.2V383h303.4c0,0-3.5-20.6-9.7-26.8H227.8z M552.9,356.2V383h182.5l-9-26.8H552.9z M815.8,356.2l-9,26.8h181.8v-26.8H815.8z M64.8,408.3v26.9h82.6v-26.9H64.8z M282.6,408.3v26.9h82.6v-26.9H282.6z M445.6,408.3v26.9h82.6c0,0,5.2-14.2,5.2-26.9H445.6z M607.8,408.3v26.9h146.5l-9.8-26.9H607.8z M797.8,408.3l-9.8,26.9h147.2v-26.9H797.8z M64.8,460.5v26.8h82.6v-26.8H64.8z M282.6,460.5v26.8h211c0,0,17.7-13.8,23.3-26.8H282.6z M607.8,460.5v26.8h82.6v-14.9l5.2,14.9h151.3l5.6-14.9v14.9h82.6v-26.8H780.1l-8.2,22.7l-8.3-22.7H607.8z M64.8,512.7v26.8h82.6v-26.8H64.8z M282.6,512.7v26.8h234.3c-5.6-13-23.3-26.8-23.3-26.8H282.6z M607.8,512.7v26.8h82.6v-26.8H607.8z M705.4,512.7l10,26.8h113.5l9.5-26.8H705.4z M852.6,512.7v26.8h82.6v-26.8H852.6z M64.8,564.8v26.8h82.6v-26.8H64.8z M282.6,564.8v26.8h82.6v-26.8H282.6z M445.6,564.8v26.8h87.9c0-12.7-5.2-26.8-5.2-26.8H445.6z M607.8,564.8v26.8h82.6v-26.8H607.8z M724.1,564.8l9.7,26.8h76.1l9.8-26.8H724.1z M852.6,564.8v26.8h82.6v-26.8H852.6z M11.5,617v26.9h190.8V617H11.5z M227.8,617v26.9h293.7c6.2-6.1,9.7-26.9,9.7-26.9H227.8z M554.4,617v26.9h135.9V617H554.4z M742.9,617l10,26.9h38.7l9.3-26.9H742.9z M852.6,617v26.9H990V617H852.6z M11.5,669.2V696h190.8v-26.8H11.5z M227.8,669.2V696h207.3c36.8,0,64.5-26.8,64.5-26.8H227.8z M554.4,669.2V696h135.9v-26.8H554.4z M761.8,669.2l9.6,26.7l1.6,0l9.7-26.8H761.8z M852.6,669.2V696H990v-26.8H852.6z";

    private final int MIN_BUTTON_SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();

        // Old image works fine.
        // svg.setContent(OLD_SVG);

        // New image does not.
        svg.setContent(NEW_SVG);

        Button buttonWithGraphics = new Button();
        buttonWithGraphics.setGraphic(svg);
        buttonWithGraphics.setPrefSize(100, 50);

        // Bind the Image scale property to the buttons size
        svg.scaleXProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.widthProperty().divide(100));
        svg.scaleYProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.heightProperty().divide(100));

        // Declare a minimum size for the button
        buttonWithGraphics.setMinSize(MIN_BUTTON_SIZE, MIN_BUTTON_SIZE);

        root.getChildren().addAll(buttonWithGraphics);
        root.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldBounds, newBounds) -> {
            double size = Math.max(MIN_BUTTON_SIZE, Math.min(newBounds.getWidth(), newBounds.getHeight()));
            buttonWithGraphics.setPrefSize(size, size);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Problem is that while the SVG image I used in that question got resized with the `Button`, my new image does not. It is displayed, it's just not resized.

If I test the SVG path in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qruudrs2/1/) the image doesn't get displayed at all. If I instead use the path from the SVG image I used in my old question, that gets displayed. I don't know what to make of this fact, because as I said: In my JavaFX program the image is displayed, it's just not resized with the `Button`.

Why isn't the `SVGPath` resized correctly and why isn't it displayed in JSFiddle when it can be displayed in a JavaFX program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVG is just too large to be scaled appropriately with those factors.

Something like

```
svg.scaleXProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.widthProperty().multiply(0.0005));
svg.scaleYProperty().bind(buttonWithGraphics.heightProperty().multiply(0.0005));
```

should work.

---

Alternatively you could determine the scale factor based on the size of the svg to make the size relative to the `Button`. The following code also preserves the ratio of the sides:

```
DoubleBinding scaleFactor = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    Bounds bounds = svg.getBoundsInLocal();
    double sx = buttonWithGraphics.getWidth() / bounds.getWidth();
    double sy = buttonWithGraphics.getHeight() / bounds.getHeight();
    return 0.8 * Math.min(sx, sy); // make svg 80% of the button in the "more restrictive" direction
}, svg.boundsInLocalProperty(), buttonWithGraphics.widthProperty(), buttonWithGraphics.heightProperty());

svg.scaleXProperty().bind(scaleFactor);
svg.scaleYProperty().bind(scaleFactor);
```

---

> If I test the SVG path in JSFiddle the image doesn't get displayed at all.

That's because the `<svg>` element is to small. Also you close the `<svg>` tag twice in the JSFiddle. Try with `<svg width=1000 height=1000>`

```html
<svg height=1000 width=1000>
  <path d="M10,304v26.8h190.8V304H10z M227.8,304v26.8h271.8c0,0-27.8-26.8-64.5-26.8H227.8z M552.9,304v26.8h164.5l-9.8-26.8H552.9z M835.3,304l-9.8,26.8h163V304H835.3z M10,356.2V383h190.8v-26.8H10z M227.8,356.2V383h303.4c0,0-3.5-20.6-9.7-26.8H227.8z M552.9,356.2V383h182.5l-9-26.8H552.9z M815.8,356.2l-9,26.8h181.8v-26.8H815.8z M64.8,408.3v26.9h82.6v-26.9H64.8z M282.6,408.3v26.9h82.6v-26.9H282.6z M445.6,408.3v26.9h82.6c0,0,5.2-14.2,5.2-26.9H445.6z M607.8,408.3v26.9h146.5l-9.8-26.9H607.8z M797.8,408.3l-9.8,26.9h147.2v-26.9H797.8z M64.8,460.5v26.8h82.6v-26.8H64.8z M282.6,460.5v26.8h211c0,0,17.7-13.8,23.3-26.8H282.6z M607.8,460.5v26.8h82.6v-14.9l5.2,14.9h151.3l5.6-14.9v14.9h82.6v-26.8H780.1l-8.2,22.7l-8.3-22.7H607.8z M64.8,512.7v26.8h82.6v-26.8H64.8z M282.6,512.7v26.8h234.3c-5.6-13-23.3-26.8-23.3-26.8H282.6z M607.8,512.7v26.8h82.6v-26.8H607.8z M705.4,512.7l10,26.8h113.5l9.5-26.8H705.4z M852.6,512.7v26.8h82.6v-26.8H852.6z M64.8,564.8v26.8h82.6v-26.8H64.8z M282.6,564.8v26.8h82.6v-26.8H282.6z M445.6,564.8v26.8h87.9c0-12.7-5.2-26.8-5.2-26.8H445.6z M607.8,564.8v26.8h82.6v-26.8H607.8z M724.1,564.8l9.7,26.8h76.1l9.8-26.8H724.1z M852.6,564.8v26.8h82.6v-26.8H852.6z M11.5,617v26.9h190.8V617H11.5z M227.8,617v26.9h293.7c6.2-6.1,9.7-26.9,9.7-26.9H227.8z M554.4,617v26.9h135.9V617H554.4z M742.9,617l10,26.9h38.7l9.3-26.9H742.9z M852.6,617v26.9H990V617H852.6z M11.5,669.2V696h190.8v-26.8H11.5z M227.8,669.2V696h207.3c36.8,0,64.5-26.8,64.5-26.8H227.8z M554.4,669.2V696h135.9v-26.8H554.4z M761.8,669.2l9.6,26.7l1.6,0l9.7-26.8H761.8z M852.6,669.2V696H990v-26.8H852.6z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This answer the question, thanks! I'm not sure if I should create a new question for this follow-up question I'm about to ask, but I'll go ahead and ask it here for now: Is it possible to set the `SVGPath` to a fixed size? I my case I want to use a `Button` with some text as well as an `SVGPath` as the graphic of the button. And just adding some text to the button in my current code gives weird results. I've also tried putting the `SVGPath` inside HBox and then settings the size of that, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka transformations such as scale, translate and rotate are not taken into account by many node types that add some node as decendant. Wrapping the `SVGPath` in a `Group` but still applying the scaling to the `SVGPath` should probably work.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka BTW: to get to a fixed size, just don't include the button size in the calculations of the scale factor. Replace it with the desired size...